On edit trigger functionality from a non user
I am using the onEdit trigger quite a bit in my scripts, and I realized that it can only be triggered from a 'user' edit. ("An installable edit trigger runs when a user modifies a value in a spreadsheet.").
How can I go around this? I have a script that changes the value of a checkbox from false to true, and an edit trigger to perform an action if this checkbox is changed from false to true. The action  is performed perfectly, when I MANUALLY (as in click the checkbox myself) set it to true. However, it does not work when the script changes the value to true (per documentation edit must be made by a user).
Is there a work around for something like this? Additionally, the resolution would need to trigger a second execution (like a trigger would) because my main function scrip will timeout without a second execution.
Below is the code that listens for an edit made to said checkbox.
function insertByTrigger (e){
  let sheetName = e.source.getActiveSheet().getName();
  let ss  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let editResults = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(1,27).getValue();
  if(sheetName == "Checker" && editResults == true) {
    ss.getSheetByName(sheetName).getRange(1,27).setBackground('red');
    ss.getSheetByName(sheetName).getRange(1,27).setValue(false);
    resumeIndex();
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    ss.getSheetByName(sheetName).getRange(1,27).setBackground('white');
    console.log('cell was set to true, and then reverted to false');
  }
  else {
    console.log('Non essential update made.')
  }
}

This code works as intended when manually checked, but how can I get this to work when the results of another script set said checkbox to true?

The question doesn't include enough details: 1) The resumeIndexfunction was not declared, 2) the function that should call the insertByTrigger is not included. Other relevant details might be missing. Please add a [mcve].

insertByTrigger is an on edit trigger. So if an edit is made to the sheet it is triggered (no function calls this function). resumeIndex does not affect the functionality of this script.
Really what I'm looking for is if this function (insertByTrigger) can be called by an edit made to the sheet BY A SCRIPT (not a user).  The insertByTrigger function could be a simple console log but can it be done by an edit made by a non user.

All the relevant details should be included directly in the question. If something is irrelevant, it should not be included in the question and the code. P.D. Using upper caps will not make that something impossible to happen. Instead, you could request a feature using the Google Apps Script issue tracker an wait for Google engineers to implement it.

Upper caps were not intended to be unpleasant but text can make things come off incorrectly. That said, I believe you've answered my question. You said its impossible so no current functionality for this or known work around. I appreciate your time.

You should make the script that you intend to fire the trigger call the insertByTrigger, but first, that script should add the required properties and values to the required function parameter, e.
Example
function myFunction() {

   // do something

   // Craft the insertByTrigger required parameter

   const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   const params = {
      source: sheet.getParent(),
      range: sheet.getActiveRange()
   }

   // Call insertByTrigger

   insertByTrigger(params);

}

If the above will throws a maximum execution time limit error, instead of calling the function directly, you should have called insertByTrigger by using a time-driven trigger. As time-driven triggers can't pass the active range when the initial script is run, you will have to make the initial script somehow store the relevant information and adapt insertByTrigger to handle that. One option for this is to use the Properties Service.
There are three property stores: script, document and user. The evaluation and decision about which to use depends on factors not mentioned in the question.

I would like to do this, however, my function main function will timeout before it reaches the insertByTrigger function. For example, my main function takes 30 plus minutes to run. So I wanted to let it run, return at 5 minutes, convert checkbox to true, this would then trigger the 'resumeIndex' function, return at 5 minutes, set checkbox to true, trigger 'resumeIndex', etc etc etc until it goes through all indexes to complete the original task.

I extended my answer.
